# convert temperature in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I put value from `input`(that is dynamically changing) in a `json` object to convert i.e `K` to `C`? Or how should I actually write such conversion if my thoughts are bad?

The way I am thinking is (i.e `K` to `C`):

```js
var quantities= [
    {
            'name': 'Temperature',
            'properties': [
                {
                    'name': 'Kelwin',
                    'symbol': 'K',
                    'units': {
                        'K': 1,
                        'C': 'inputValue + 273.15',
                        'F': '(inputValue + 459.67)*5/9'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Celsius',
                    'symbol': 'C',
                    'units': {
                        'K': 'inputValue - 273.15',
                        'C': 1,
                        'F': '(inputValue - 32)*5/9'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Fahrenheit',
                    'symbol': 'F',
                    'units': {
                        'K': 'inputValue * 9/5-459.67',
                        'C': 'inputValue * 9/5+32',
                        'F': 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
    
    var optionsIndex = $('select.from option:selected').index();
    var from = $('select.from option:selected').val(); 
    var to = $('select.to option:selected').val();

    var fromSelectTypeValue = quantities[0].properties[optionsIndex].units[from];
    var toSelectTypeValue = quantities[0].properties[optionsIndex].units[to];

    var result = fromSelectTypeValue  * toSelectTypeValue;
    //fromSelectType = 1 (because K is choosen in first select element)
    //toSelectTypeValue = 'inputValue + 273.15' (because C is choosen in second select element)

    var $inputs = $('.inputValue, select.from, select.to');
      $inputs.on('keyup change', function () {
            $('.result').val(result);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="inputValue" placeholder="Insert value" />
<br />
<select class="from">
  <option value="K">Kelvin</option>
  <option value="C">Celsius</option>
  <option value="F">Fahrenheit</option>
</select>

<select class="to">
  <option value="K">Kelvin</option>
  <option value="C">Celsius</option>
  <option value="F">Fahrenheit</option>
</select> 
<br />

<input type="numer" class="result" placeholder="Result" readonly />
```

Comment: isn't `fromSelectType` always 1? btw, what this is boiling down to in the end, is the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) ... just sayin ...

Comment: btw, CodeReview might be a better place for this question ...

Comment: This would not be a good fit for Code Review as the OP seems to be asking for help on how to do something, rather than asking for review of code which is already working as intended.

Comment: Unless this is intended to be used for doing numerous types of conversions you are making something simple overly complicated

Comment: Is your object `quantities` actually retrieved from a service, or do you just configure that in code to store how to do your conversions? I ask, because if the latter, then you can just make some of that functions rather than a textual representation of the formula.

Comment: this isn't json...

Comment: main problem...this is not json

Comment: @charlietfl Besides `temperature quantity` i have all other physics stuff like `length`, `mass`, `volume` etc, so i've decided to put everything in json to make code more clean.
@Jamiec No it is not. I do that in code to store how I do my conversions.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob and Liam, Well, then an array with objects; still new to that topic in js.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for fast reply and brief explanation to few things. Appreciate it.

Comment: @charlietfl Actually I have 1 more question. Is it OK to actually go with `JSON.stringify(quantities)` and then `JSON.parse(parsedQuantities)` to make it `json`?

Comment: @nehel not when using functions as per Jameic answer. Would need  completely different way to reference functions included in actual javascript...or use `eval()` which is bad practice due to security

Comment: Aight, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got this entirely the wrong way round - you dont put your value "dynamically  into your JSON", you make your javascript configuration object able to deal with dynamic values.

For example, your conversaions should be actual functions, rather than textual representations of those functions (which are hard to "execute" safely).

```
var quantities= [
   {
        'name': 'Temperature',
        'properties': [
            {
                'name': 'Kelwin',
                'symbol': 'K',
                'units': {
                    'K': function(input){ return input; },
                    'C': function(input){ return input + 273.15; },
                    'F': function(input){ return (input + 459.67)*5/9; }
                }
            },
      ....
```

Then, assuming you know how to pull the right function out your object, you just execute the function:

```
var kToC = quantities[0].properties[0].units.C; // assume you know how to look this up
var c = kToC(123); // execute the function (convert 123 k to c)
```

Comment: Ah, didnt know I can put function there x) Thanks for explaining that. Appreciate it.

Comment: @nehel thats why people were querying whether this was really a JSON object, or just a plain old javascript object. There is no sensible way to pass functions in JSON, but a javascript object can store anything.